# Keyboard navigation of Mac OS X Finder window's search options toolbar

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

When I'm in a Finder window and enter terms in the spotlight search box (top right of window) and then press the TAB key the search location bar appears just below and the focus moves to the first location (usually "This Mac") shown (as it should).  But then the focus seems locked in place and no keyboard key or combination I've found will get it to move (most of the time, that is; at times it's possible to select one of the shown locations with the keyboard and sometimes I've found it possible to tab to the Save button or Add Option [+] button and on to the options themselves but most times it just gets stuck [like now!] and I need to use the mouse).  I've been annoyed by this for years now and am running out of new key combinations to try!  Is there a way to continue with specifying the search info using the keyboard?

Comment: This is off topic, you should ask on [apple.se]

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the obvious to me – I didn't even know there was an Apple site. Considered here or Super User and found similar things here but I'll repost there.